# How can I run the same method in all instances of a class?

Tags: javascript, class, object, methods

I have a class that constructs objects. Can I run a method in all the object instances without knowing the names of the objects themselves?

```
class Person{

 constructor (_a){
 this.a = _a;
 }

 sayfood(){
 console.log(this.a);
 }

}

let person1 = new Person("cheese");
let person2 = new Person("milk");
```

My current best solution is to loop through the instances like this:

```
for (var i = 1; i < 3; i++) {
  eval("person" + i).sayfood();
}
```

It works, but I imagine there is a better way. I have tried placing the new object instances as elements of an array, and then iterating through them using *foreach*, but I could not get that working.

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ofaycs57/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I have tried placing the new object instances as elements of an array, and then iterating through them using foreach, but I could not get that working.

That would indeed be a better way. This is how you would use `forEach` to achieve that:

```js
class Person{
 constructor (_a){
  this.a = _a;
 }

 sayFood(){
  console.log(this.a);
 }
}

const person1 = new Person("cheese");
const person2 = new Person("milk");

const persons = [person1, person2]

persons.forEach(person => person.sayFood())
```